# Restart Xfce panel in Xubuntu

Tags: xfce

I am running Xubuntu 16.04.2 LTS with Xfce 4.12

I have customized the panel, but after saving the changes I got the message:

> "Please restart the panel for visibility changes to take effect."

How can I restart the panel?

Comment: You could try rebooting

Answer (score 80, accepted):

To restart the panel, open the terminal and run the following command:

```
xfce4-panel -r
```

Your changes should be visible now.

---

The `-r` option stands for *restart*, as described in [the man page](http://manpages.org/xfce4-panel):

> **-r**, **--restart**
>
> *Restart the running panel instance*

Comment: In my case the -r only stopped and not started the panel :\ Could be me..

Comment: Works in Arch Linux with Xfce as well. Thanks.

Comment: For me, this made the panel vanish completely, and furthermore the panel configuration tool from the Settings Manager will no longer launch. (On 19.10 now.)

Comment: Worked for display problems in Linux Lite which internally uses xfce as DE

Comment: This also just made the panel disappear just now (and the process stop, as observed by ps).

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes I find that, xfce panel is gone. Therefore I need to restart the panel.

Above restart process do not work 100%. In my system, it cannot initialize session-buttons and other add-on(s).

To complete panel restart, just open the task manager and kill the xfce4-panel process. Don't worry. System will restart the panel just after is has been killed.

Answer (score 1):

```
pkill xfce4-panel ; xfce4-panel &
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think you'd be better off killing the panel process first, try this:

```
#!/bin/sh

panelcommand=$(ps aux | grep -e "xfce4-panel" | grep -e "--display" | awk '{print $11,$12,$13,$14,$15}')

ps aux | grep -e "xfce4-panel" | grep -e "--display" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill

$panelcommand
```

Works fine in Debian 07 (Wheezy).